# When are multiple t-tests a problem?

Tags: t-test, assumptions

I have two independent variables, both with two levels. Different participants for each of the 4 conditions.

A 2x2 ANOVA does not seem to be the best solution because my sample is small, the number of participants in each conditions differs, and the normality assumption is not met. I did the Shapiro-Wilk test in SPSS after I used the split data option, and it was significant for some conditions.

Is it possible to perform a seperate t-test for both independent variables? 
I know that multiple t-tests lead to an increased chance of Type I errors, but I always thought this was a problem only for independent variables with three levels or more.

I am not sure whether doing multiple t-tests but for different independent variables also leads to the increased chance of Type 1 error.

Comment: All the reasons given to suspect ANOVA apply to t-tests, too.  It would be more constructive to ask for specific advice rather than to propose a procedure that might be problematic and just have it get shot down.

Comment: But the normality assumption was only violated when I used the Split Data option before carrying out the normality tests. I have to test it this way if I want to do a 2x2 ANOVA. The normality assumption was met for both independent variables if I did not use Split Data before the S-W test. Therefore I thought that 2 seperate t-tests are better than 2x2 ANOVA.

Comment: It's not clear what "normality assumptions" you are referring to.  ANOVA makes no assumptions whatsoever about the independent variables: they are considered fixed. The only distributional assumptions it makes is about residuals.

Comment: If you do multiple testing some adjustment of the p-value should be calculate.  With just two tests it may not change the p-value much.  But why do you think the two t test are like doing a 2x2 ANOVA?